Validate implicit 'undefined' value in optional Zod field
This Zod validation fails when the provided value is a "undefined" string.
const schema = z.string().time().optional()

This leads to undesired behaviour, as the form is invalidated. My guess is the time method return false, because "undefined" is not coerced to its primitive type.
What's the simplest way to handle this edge case using Zod?

so you want string undefined to work the same as literal undefined, right? but why not pass actual undefined? also are you sure that if fails on "undefined" but not on "" I'd expect to be sent as a form field value?

I think you might be casting an undefined into string on form submission. I think just omitting that specific field (if it is undefined) when submitting the form would get your desired behavior.

@skyboyer On the server, the form field value is received as an actual undefined string. I agree with you that passing undefined directly might be simpler. So how would you modify the form data before validation?

@Zxeenu What's the best practice to omit an undefined form field on submission? Is it more robust to access the submitted form data or just remove the name attribute of the specific form field?

@Clemens Rosenow I think your use case could benefit from a programmatic form submission, so that you can determine which fields to include in the form data that is sent to the server.
